# Blanked a Win10 password but cannot login

Tags: windows, password-recovery

Okay, I think I did something stupid here. I had forgotten my Win10 user account (steph) Password. This is an admin account.

1) Using a Linux-type usb-boot utility, I've been able to blank the password. Upon reboot, I entered a blank password but I still cannot login, it seems that my account physically on the computer now doesn't match my Hotmail credentials -or something- and I'm still locked out.

2) Using the same Linux usb boot utility, I've unlocked the 'Administrator' account. Now I can login using the 'Administrator' account but from the Control Panel, I cannot change my own user account (steph) password, the option for it is just not there (perhaps it's because the password is believed to be blank?)

3) Later I've been able to find the piece of paper on which I wrote my original password for my own account.

Q: Is there's a way to set my original password back to what it was in order to unlock my account?

Thanks.

Comment: `net user username password` from an administrative command prompt.

Comment: This cannot work: it is a 'Connected Account'  (Error 8646)

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux usb boot utilities can work with local account only. I suggest you set up a new Microsoft account on your PC, and point it to your old profile directory. Then remove your original Microsoft account from Control Panel.